# Swapfile mount (/etc/fstab): "swap swap" or "none swap"

Tags: mount, swap, fstab, swapping

There seems to be conflicting information on how to mount a swapfile.

[`swap swap`](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04/):

[image]

[`none swap`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04):

[image]

[both](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/setting_up_swap.html):

[image]

Both ways work. **What is the official recommendation and how does each way affect swapping?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In regard to the second field, for swap partitions, the Linux man page for fstab states:

> For swap partitions, this field should be specified as `none'.

It has stated the same thing since at least 27 November 1993, the earliest man page I could find.

In practice it doesn't matter; if the filesystem type is swap, the system ignores the mountpoint field. I have one system where it is literally set to `whatever` and works fine.

```
UUID=b81f37e8-eddf-4969-9cea-8fdea73bd125 whatever        swap    defaults        0 0
```

But using the word "none" is intended to make it clear that the field is not relevant to the entry.